# How to select an option from the Select

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

This is my scenario:

1. I add a new group in the list
2. Once the group is added, I need to select the newly added group from the left window and add it to the right window.

I am not sure how to select. The following is my script so far:

```
Select selectNewGroup = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("GroupTemp")));
    selectNewGroup.getOptions();
    selectNewGroup.selectByValue(group_id);
    selectNewGroup.getFirstSelectedOption().click();
```

When I run this script, I get the following error. PLEASE NOTE that the value in the error is the same value that I sent for the new group.

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Cannot locate option with value: AOscar_20150114160136
```

Comment: here is the image url    http://imgur.com/bSMZWqY

Comment: selectByValue will find element whose attribute **value** matches group_id. You should do it with selectByVisibleText.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using text instead of value. See the image below. You may want to do `selectByVisibleText` instead and use the text. Check other options of `Select` class [here](https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/Select.html)

[image]

Comment: Nice!, Now how would I click and select this item in the list. I don't see any option in the select class, because this is NOT the first item in the list either...Thanks guys!

Comment: There is no click needed. All you do is `selectNewGroup.selectByValue("value you want");` if you want to use `selectByVisibleText` then click on the `select` element and open the dropdown list.

Comment: It selects the item in the left window, but after a few seconds, generates the same error in console "Cannot locate option with value: ABCDED...In the UI it seems fine.

Comment: Okay the `id` of the select element on the picture is different. Are you sure you are using correct id? it says `campaignGroupTemp`

Comment: Yes, the id on the pic is the correct one, for a bit of privacy, i had changed it in the initial code that I posted :)

Comment: Do you know if both select list have the same id?

Comment: The left list id is different from the right list id

Comment: So, i restarted the entire set up and ran it again, and IT WORKED!!!!! You guys did it Again! :)